# INSERT INTO, Based on a COUNT in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm inserting supplier records into my table based on the types of products they have supplied.

I'm doing something like this;

```
INSERT INTO RedItems (ID, Name, NumItems)
SELECT ID, Name, NULL
FROM supplier
WHERE status = 'Supplier'
```

However, I only want to add the suppliers that have supplied **at least one** 'Red' item.

There is no particular field for 'Red' items, 'Red' is a type in the products column.

How do I construct my WHERE clause in this way?

**EDIT**

**Supplier** (table)

```
ID    /    Name    /    Status     /     Product
1     /    Smith   /     Supplier    /    Red
2     /    Baxter   /     Supplier    /    Round
```

**RedItems** (table)

```
ID    /    Name    /    NumItems
1     /    Smith    /       23
```

Where NumItems is the total (red) items from that supplier.

Comment: where do you store the indicator of `red` items?

Comment: Red is something in the 'product' field. I.E. within the product field there could be red, blue, round, square etc.

Comment: @William231 where is the product field? please show the table structures.

Comment: Please, add the schema of the 'mytable' table and, if it is related to other tables, their structure too. It would be also helpful to have some sample data in order to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is in the same table, then you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO RedItems (ID, Name, NumItems)
SELECT ID, Name, count(product)
FROM mytable
WHERE status = 'Supplier'
  AND product = 'red'
GROUP BY ID, Name
```

If not, then

```
INSERT INTO RedItems (ID, Name, NumItems)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, count(p.product)
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN products p
   ON t1.id = p.supplierID
WHERE t1.status = 'Supplier'
   and p.product = 'red'
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

> I only want to add the suppliers that have supplied at least one 'Red'
>   item

```
INSERT INTO RedItems (ID, Name, NumItems)
SELECT ID, Name, COUNT(Product)
FROM supplier
WHERE status = 'Supplier'
  AND Product = 'RED'
GROUP BY ID, Name
HAVING COUNT(Product) >= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO RedItems (ID, Name, NumItems) 
SELECT suppliers.ID, suppliers.Name, count(distinct products.id)
FROM suppliers
    inner join products on suppliers.id = products.supplierid
WHERE status = 'Supplier' and products.type='red'
group by suppliers.ID, suppliers.Name
```